# Are there commercial airplanes on which I can access the Internet from my mobile phone?

Tags: air-travel, internet

I'm wondering if there are airlines that provide Internet access to passengers when flying longer than 2 hours, and if it's technically possible at all.

Comment: This is too broad and also answers will become outdated almost immediately. The eventual answer is "yes there is wifi" for every airline and plane, the only question is when.

Comment: "When will be WIFI on every airplane" is a whole other question that I'm not interested in...

Comment: @chx How can a yes/no question be too broad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, many airlines provide internet access on their flights. The plane connects to the internet by satellite and makes a WiFi network available for passengers.

Usually, you have to pay to use it, and they don't allow high-bandwidth activities like video and VOIP. Some carriers also make their in-flight entertainment available over the WiFi, for people who'd prefer to use their own device instead of the screen in the back of the seat. Some give free access to a limited range of sites (Delta lets you use Whatsapp and, I think, Facebook).

Answer (score 4):

Yes: [List of Airlines Offering Inflight WiFi](https://www.edreams.com/blog/in-flight-wifi/)

Answer (score 4):

Its for sure possible, many airlines do often at a cost. As for the technical details [check out this question.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14849/how-does-wifi-work-on-an-aircraft) It may depend as much about the aircraft in question as it does the airline.